# Installing Mercurial on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to install Mercurial on Mac OSX 10.6, but I'm having problems:

1. I have Mac OS X 10.6, so I downloaded Mercurial 1.4.3 for OS X 10.6 from http://mercurial.berkwood.com/
2. I install the downloaded file `mercurial-1.4.3+20100201-py2.6-macosx10.6.mpkg`
3. Than, I open Terminal and run `hg --version` to make sure it's installed. and it says

> hg: command not found

How do I install Mercurial on Mac OS X 10.6?

Comment: It really says " **hd** : command not found" when you type " **hg** --version"?

Comment: sorry, it says hg, not hd. my bad spelling at post. just edited.

Comment: This is an installation issue, not a programming issue, so I think it goes in SuperUser.  In any case, I just downloaded it for 10.5, double-clicked on the mpkg file, clicked on anything that said "Continue" or "Agree" or "Install", and it worked.  I think step 2 needs more clarification before anybody can help you.

Comment: at Terminal, do I have to be under any particular path to run this hg comments? or do I actually first have to run anything about Mercurial to make it work? or does it just works?

Answer (score 4):

Mercurial installs itself in `/usr/local/bin`, so the executable you want is `/usr/local/bin/hg`. You just need to add that directory to your `PATH` variable, i.e. do something like

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

somewhere in your shell profile (`.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`).

PS: I only ever used Mercurial once, a week ago, and this particular information is displayed during installation, and again available as part of the package documentation. Not very hard to find :)

Comment: aha! after I run the comment you said, hg --version worked!! it said "Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.4.3+20100201) Copyright (C) 2005-2010 Matt Mackall <mpm@selenic.com> and others. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE." so, it means MErcurial is working? hmmm, now I need to find out more about Mercurial comments i guess

Comment: whooaaa! do I have to do this export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" everything i need to work with mercurial? I closed Terminal, than opened again and hg didnt work again. after I make this export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH", it worked. so this export comment is sth to run mercurial? do i have to do all the time?

Comment: as the OP noted, you need to put that line in your profile.  If you don't know how to add it, just type this in a new terminal window "touch ~/.bash_profile && open -e ~/.bash_profile".  That will open it up in text edit and you can paste the "export PATH..." command in there and save it.  Open a new terminal window and you're good to go for all future terminal sessions.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this:

go download the proper version of mercurial (mac didn't have it)

```
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads
```

Make sure you grab the version of your MAc then not only make sure it's in your path like F'x said, but also make sure you have an alias set for it to execute from any directory:

```
alias hg=/path/where/mercurial/installed
```

for me it was

```
/usr/local/bin/hg
```

Hope this helps someone. It took me an hour to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it wasn't the `$PATH` variable. That was already set to /usr/local/bin. However when I ran sudo su and performed `ls -al /usr/local`, bin was set only to 700 with "wheel" user. Though, probably not the most secure, I set this to `chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin` and then I could run `hg --version` from any command line (as well as IntelliJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the installer  from [Mercurial Downloads](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads).Donwload the required version from list of Just double click and it will instal mercurial for you